# Deselect combo box when form starts up

Tags: c#, winforms

I have form 1 and form 2.

From form 1 I have a button that directs me to form 2.

On form 2 I have Combo Box and few text boxes.

The problem is that every time I enter form 2 then my combo box is selected and when user clicks on any letter it appears in combo box.

How can I deselect this field? So user isn't pointed to this combo box at start?

And second question, how can I disable editing text from combo box completely? that the only choice user have is to pick one of 3 selected items?

Regards.

Comment: try to change the tab order of form 2, probably your combobox has taborder nr 0, make it higher and the startup focus will be on another thing (as far as i know)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) [Set the Tab Order on the form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd16a8cw.aspx) so that the correct control is selected when the form is activated

2) To disable text entry in the combo and thus restrict selection to the defined items only, set the combo's [DropDownStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.dropdownstyle.aspx) to [DropDownList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.comboboxstyle.aspx)

Comment: Ok! Great, the new stye works better. I will change tab index later. Thanks!